# Microsoft Outlook 2013 Interaction from Electron JS Desktop App

Tags: c#, .net, electron, office-interop, edgejs

Have a requirement, where I need to connect to **installed Microsoft Outlook Application** and perform the following tasks:

- Create/Read/Update/Delete **Outlook Calendar Events**
- Create/Read/Update/Delete **Outlook Contacts**

Need to sync these entities with the Electron JS Desktop app.

What I have tried so far:

- Tried [electron-edge-js/edge-js](https://github.com/agracio/electron-edge-js), but this couldn't detect
  Microsoft Office Interop assemblies.
- Tried installing Visual Studio Code and starting Electron.Net application. This has too many issues to work with. No .Net C#
  expertise, Client App does not reload on change, difficult to develop
  the project. Don't want to merge Angular   Electron project just to
  sync those entities. maintenance would be difficult.

Need guidelines on how could this be achieved from the Electron JS Desktop app itself and without the .Net/C# environment. Looking for a solution that will work with windows installed Outlook application, and also with OSX installed Outlook application.

**NOTE:** Do not confuse this with Office 365 APIs. This is an old Outlook native application that adds emails from the system and works with Outlook Data files(.pst, .olm, .ost).

Comment: Are you talking about creating Outlook Add-In? Doing this will also add a GUI button in Outlook App right? Also, just to confirm what you suggesting, I will need to post data from Add-in to the server then get that data from the server in Electron App, right? This will add 1 extra layer but at least I got the hint to try something

Comment: Ok! Thank you :) I will revert once I try and succeed. If I don't, I failed :p

Comment: Even if I achieve this it won't be able to run in the background or without starting the outlook application! Also, I will need APIs to reverse sync and get data in outlook. I am still going to try

Answer (score -1):

The solution with https://github.com/agracio/electron-edge-js works fine for me.
In order to make Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook available you need to [specify](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-specify-additional-clr-assembly-references-in-c-code) path to microsoft.office.interop.outlook.dll in the references array.